# Drag+Drop image uploader for Chat

Tags: script, chat, images

[image]

Drag and Drop images into chat! In any chat window, simply drag and drop an image to anywhere in the window to upload it. **Bonus!** - the image will *not* be automatically sent, allowing you to edit your message before sending!

## [Userscript download](https://gist.github.com/fredley/f130e8628c1d61c7b5a2)

1. Download the file
2. Drag and Drop onto your Extensions page in Chrome, or install with Greasemonkey in FF

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Also support pasting an image from the clipboard.

Thank you for this, this is awesome. But if you also add the paste feature that imgur has (it also works on Stack Exchange posts, hit the "insert image" icon and Ctrl+V), I will worship you<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: For very specific definitions of "worship." Offer void on weekdays or days that start with "S." Terms and conditions apply.</sup>

Comment: So I've spent a little while looking into this, and I don't think it's going to be possible. For the main site image uploader, there's something going on where SE helps marshal the pasted data-blob over to imgur. There's no simple way (given the level of access possible from a userscript) to inject the pasted image into existing upload mechanism, or to otherwise trick it into handling the data. If someone else wants to try (and compete for Doorknob's worship) please do!